# Function to convert a z-score into a percentage

Tags: math

Google doesn't want to help!

I'm able to calculate z-scores, and we are trying to produce a function that given a z-score gives us a percent of the population in a normal distribution that would be under that z-score.  All I can find are references to z-score to percentage tables.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it [this z-score (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) you're talking about?

If so, the function you're looking for is called the [normal cumulative distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_cumulative_distribution_function#Cumulative_distribution_function), also sometimes referred to as the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (although Wikipedia defines the two slightly differently). How to calculate it depends on what programming environment you're using.

Comment: but you need raw value, not z-score to apply it.

Comment: No, actually the first thing you do when calculating the normal CDF from a raw value is to convert it to a z-score. Only the z-score gets plugged into the formula.

Comment: That's the z-score we are using. Thanks for the pointer to the name of the function I was looking. Searches for that yield a lot more results!

Answer (score 3):

If you're programming in C++, you can do this with the Boost library, which has routines for working with [normal distributions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/dist_ref/dists/normal_dist.html).  You are looking for the `cdf` accessor function, which takes a z-score as input and returns the probability you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code snippet for python:

```
import math

def percentage_of_area_under_std_normal_curve_from_zcore(z_score):
    return .5 * (math.erf(z_score / 2 ** .5) + 1)
```

Using the following photo for reference:
http://www.math.armstrong.edu/statsonline/5/cntrl8.gif

The z-score is 1.645, and that covers 95 percent of the area under the standard normal distribution curve.

When you run the code, it looks like this:

```
>>> std_normal_percentile_from_zcore(1.645)
0.9500150944608786
```

More about the error function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: for future readers, it is the sqrt of 2: `return .5 * (math.erf(z_score /( 2 ** .5)) + 1)`

Comment: Also a good reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2560805