# Can Android's Sqlite translate a Z score into a probability or percentage?

Tags: android, eclipse, statistics, android-sqlite, normal-distribution

I'm creating an application in Eclipse for Android and would like to translate a Z score into a probability or percentage.  Is there support for this?

I have seen a reference for [PYTHON and C++ in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782284/function-to-convert-a-z-score-into-a-percentage).

This is not a statistics question of the math involved.  This is a question of whether there is an existing command or series of instructions to calculate a percentage if I already have Z score (and also mean, standard deviation, etc.)

I would prefer not to create a z-score chart and do look-up references.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seeking a statistical javascript function to return p-value from a z-score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194730/seeking-a-statistical-javascript-function-to-return-p-value-from-a-z-score)

Comment: I have attempted to flag this as duplicate: the answer seems to be that there USED TO BE a Java function in a publicly available library (jstat.ztest).  However, there is no currently defined function in the Eclipse Java IDE.